# Print a matrix line from a sparse matrix saved without 'zeros'

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix

How do I print a matrix line between 2 column indexs when I only have the non-zero indexes saved in a struct?

I need to basically, given the right most index of a matrix and the left most index of a matrix, print that matrix line between both values if there's at least one index in that line that isn't zero and if the line I want to print is between the row's bound.

I have a structure in which I store my row, column and value from each input, so that I don't have to generate a huge matrix full of 'zeros' and I have a variable that counts how many values I have stored.

```
int searchForLine(unsigned int l){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<matrixcount;i++){
        if((auxMatrix[i].line == l)&&(auxMatrix[i].column<=workingMatrix.maxCol)&&(auxMatrix[i].column>= workingMatrix.minCol))
            return (int)auxMatrix[i].value;
    }
    return (int)workingMatrix.zero;
}

void print_line(){
    unsigned int ii,i,userLine;
    scanf("%u", &userLine);
    if((userLine<workingMatrix.minLine) || (userLine>workingMatrix.maxLine)){
        printf("empty line\n");
    }
    else{
        for(ii=0;ii<matrixcount;ii++){
                if(auxMatrix[ii].line!=userLine){
                    printf("empty line\n");break;
                }else{;}
        }

        for(i=workingMatrix.minCol;i<workingMatrix.maxCol;i++){
            printf("%u ",searchForLine(userLine));
        }
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    }
```

if the input is lets say

```
3 3 3.0
3 0 4.0
print_line(3)->
4.0 0.0 0.0 3.0
```

My current code prints only 0.0's

Comment: Nowhere in code is a print of a floating-point value.  Output `4.0 0.0 0.0 3.0` is suspicious.  Post a [MCVE]

Comment: my structure auxMatrix has 
`unsigned int line, column;
 float value;`

Comment: Big Bear, rather than post code that is needed to compile in a comment, amend your post to include `struct  auxMatrix` definition.    Further, knowing the ``struct  auxMatrix` details is only one step.  Post still lacks how `4.0 0.0 0.0 3.0` was printed.  Post a [mcve] to improve the post and receive good feedback.